# Add a package into eclipse that is notj in src directory

Tags: eclipse

How to add a packed called `com.easyndk.classes` to my project when the package source files are here: `3rdParty/EasyNDK/AndroidNDKHelper/com/easyndk/classes` and not in `src` directory? (They should not be in `src` dir.)

Answer (score 1):

Properties -> Build Path -> Source -> Link Source

(at least in Luna)

Comment: Works! Just want to mention here you should right click on the project you want to add a package and select Properties->Java Build Path->Source (tab)->Link Source with my version of ADT.